# Using a store with Postgres HSTORE in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, store, hstore

I have a **User** Model with a database field **'remark'**. I am using Postgres as Database and the 'remark' field is of type **HSTORE**. So 'remark' stores a hash with extra user information.

As suggested by someone I added a store to my 'User' model like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :remark, accessors: [ :info ]
  #some code
end
```

Now I can get the value in **@user.remark['info']** by using this accessor **'@user.info'**. That works fine. But when I try to set and **save** a new value like this:

```
@user.info = "some info"
@user.save
```

I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InternalError: ERROR:  Syntax error near '!' at position 4
```

Is it possible to use a HSTORE type databasefield this way? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code you have posted looks okay.  Are you sure the exception is coming from setting hstore values?  Do you have any callbacks that might be throwing an error?  What does the generated sql update command look like (try in console or look in your rails logs).

Comment: SQL (0.8ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "remark" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["remark", "--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess\ninfo: dit zou moeten werken\n"], ["updated_at", "2015-09-28 13:22:04.216668"], ["id", 1]]
PG::InternalError: ERROR:  Syntax error near '!' at position 4
: UPDATE "users" SET "remark" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3

Comment: Does it work with `@user.remark['info']  = "some info"; @user.save`?

Comment: no does'nt work either. I just saw that @user.save is not working. even if I don't change the instance. And When I delete the "store :remark, accessors: [ :info ]" from the model it does work. (using rails 4.2 and ruby2.1.1)

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom coder to *store*:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :remark, accessors: [ :info ], coder: HstoreCoder
  #some code
end
```

*HstoreCoder* class:

```
class HstoreCoder
  class << self
    def load(hash)
      hash
    end

    def dump(value)
      value.to_hash
    end
  end
end
```

It should help.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 5 and hstore use `store_accessor` instead of `store`

```
store_accessor :remark, :info
```

> NOTE: If you are using PostgreSQL specific columns like hstore or json there is no need for the serialization provided by .store. Simply use .store_accessor instead to generate the accessor methods. Be aware that these columns use a string keyed hash and do not allow access using a symbol.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html